# Curl PHP getting/download file from dynamic link

Tags: php, file, dynamic, curl, download

Need to download using cURL from dynamic generated link

link: something.com/fileid=hgkjfdhgfhdg

if access directly link it'll show download box (file save option).

but if use CURL or file_get_contents its return only filename.

```
$URL = https://somewebsite.com/fileid=hgkjfdhgfhdg
$fp = fopen("test.txt", 'w');
$c = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
$contents = curl_exec($c);
$info = curl_getinfo($c);
curl_close($c); 
fclose($fp);
```

filename from dynamic link (test.txt) is already known.

URL = https://storage-ec2-32.sharefile.com/download.ashx?dt=dtca3192857a45452c84bd14e7500c7f46

Comment: are you trying to download from sites like `rapidshare.com` ? FYI they use javascript and you need to simulate javascripts (e.g. timer, ajax token)

Comment: Have you tried to use a packet sniffing utility (e.g. Wireshark) to check what happens at the HTTP level? I suspect that this is due to the site accepting or refusing the download because some identification cookies are (or are not) present.

Comment: Shiplu, it is ShareFile, and here is direct download link for download https://storage-ec2-32.sharefile.com/download.ashx?dt=dtca3192857a45452c84bd14e7500c7f46  it'll show you download box with test.txt

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the fact that you're connecting to an HTTPS URL and the cURL library is unable to find the root CA certificates bundle needed to prove the authenticity of the ShareFile certificate. As a result of this, cURL acts on the safe side and aborts the connection before initiating file transfer.

The best way to solve this problem would be to set the [curl_cainfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php) PHP configuration switch in php.ini to the absolute path of a file containing all the CA certificates you'd need (as per the [PHP help page describing the cURL configuration switches](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)), and then restart the server.

If you're unable to do that, you might disable SSL certificate verification entirely by adding

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

to your code, just above the `$contents = curl_exec($c);` line.

Be wary that this last solution is unsafe and might open the door to man in the middle attacks, though - use it as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);   make no difference.

Comment: One last question, are you sure you have properly quoted the original URL in the script? (It worked for me if I added the above-mentioned code line).

Comment: Also, if it still does not work, could you add a `die(curl_error());` line just after the `curl_exec()` call? That would show what the error is.

Comment: Thanks elgaton, as I already provided the link above and you said it works for you, it'll be nice if you can post the exact code here so I can test it (if its possible for you).

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/3QK1PUXf. I've added some simple error detection. Note that today it seems that the download link has expired, if you replace it with a fresh one it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot elgaton, I found a solution using FTPS.

Comment: You're welcome - however, I still wonder why the original approach did not work for you (since it did for me). Maybe there was a firewall/PHP configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set CURLOPT_HEADER to 0 to prevent header in the output. Second, are you sure that file you are opening is writable? You should check the result of `fopen` and `curl_setopt`.

Comment: with CURLOPT_HEADER no success, url is https://storage-ec2-32.sharefile.com/download.ashx?dt=dtca3192857a45452c84bd14e7500c7f46